# Background-Image behind Header Section with CSS Grid

Tags: css, grid, background-image, css-grid

i'm trying to recreate this template through the use of Grid. I can't figure how to create the background-image behind what i've already created 
in my markup. Image what i'm after [refrence image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10QyU.jpg) any tips?

check my [website](http://www.michalmacko.com), what have i already done, i thought to use z-indexing, but it didn't worked.. also if i apply it to the body, it will stretch with the additional content after the header section.

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif, arial;
}

a{
  color: black;
}

body{
background-color: red;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 80%;
}

/* .background-image{
  background-image: url(../img/bgheader.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
} */

#grid-container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12,1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

header{
  grid-column: 1 / 13;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 11fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 10fr 1fr 4fr;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

header ul{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

header ul li:nth-child(-n+3){
  margin-right: 3rem;
}

header ul a{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
}

header a:hover{
color: grey;
}

.slogan{
 grid-row: 2 / 3;
 grid-column: 1 / 3;
 justify-self: center;
 align-self: center;
 text-align: center;
}

.slogan h1{
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.more{
  color: white;
}

.services{
  color: #4a4747;
  grid-row: 4 / 5;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20rem;
}

.services h2{
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Brackets Junior</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="grid-container">

    <!-- Header Section -->
      <header>
        <a href="#"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class="slogan">
        <h1>Always a step ahead go pro</h1>
        <a href="#" class="more">Learn more..</a>
        </div>

        <div class="services">
          <h2> We provide the best services</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia voluptatum blanditiis expedita ducimus fugit rem, qui repellat, quos totam ipsa reprehenderit eum laboriosam maiores. Eum fugit provident error velit soluta, praesentium enim dolorum architecto, quis quisquam magnam! Sequi voluptas consequatur dolor asperiores rem eaque voluptatem necessitatibus laborum alias, omnis atque.</p>
        </div>
      </header>



    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just apply your background to the header.

```
header{
  grid-column: 1 / 13;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 11fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 10fr 1fr 4fr;
  margin-top: 5rem;
  background-image: url(../img/bgheader.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I am not sure why your header includes your page contents, nor why you are placing the header grid inside the page grid.  These things might be revisited.

Answer (score 0):

write some text in header or li components and then apply min padding of 400px
or top and bottom padding of 200px. this will resolve your problem